# Flutter Basics Can Anyone explain this simple code (6 lines)

Tags: flutter

```
class Recipe {
  String label;
  String imageUrl;
  
  Recipe(
    this.label,
    this.imageUrl, 

  );
  
}
```

> Can anyone explain the above code what this means and what happening.
> Second Recipe means constructor ? How does it works and what its usage?
> what does "this" means and labels are two variables of type string right? please explain

Comment: I'll recommend you to read more about OOP languages as it's a basic concept from it and shared with so many others like Java, Kotlin, Swift, etc

Answer (score 1):

here are some explanations:

```dart
class Recipe {
  String label;      // 1
  String imageUrl;   // 2
  
  Recipe(            // 3
    this.label,      // 4
    this.imageUrl,   // 5
  );
}
```

- *1 & 2* are members of the class `Recipe`, they are both `String` properties.
- *3* is the constructor of the class `Recipe`
- *4 & 5* are the properties to construct the class, `this` refers to the property of the class. This is a simplification of the below code.

You can write this instead to create a copy of these 2 properties & then construct your class (not recommended but valid):

```dart
class Recipe {
  String label;
  String imageUrl;
  
  Recipe(
    String label,
    String imageUrl, 
  ) : this.label = label, this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```